# What is the difference between the SK1366 and K1156 Core i7?

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i7

I want to build a **Core i7** computer, but im not really sure of what is the difference between them. I am want to build a comptuer that is going to be used for **3d design**/ **render**, **CAD**, **photoshop**, **illustrator** and pretty much anything ***Adobe*** and ***AutoDesk***.

I plan to invest a considerate amount (for me, at least), of around `2,000 dollars` (including large monitor(s)), and I want the computer to be used for quite a bunch of years, perhaps buying little upgrades as time goes on.

Is there any benefit on getting the more expensive 1366?

PD I do plan to overclock it a little bit, but not to extreme levels, i want it to be a relatively silent PC.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical difference is in the socket, which means that each uses a different socket/motherboard.

The technical difference, in lay terms, is that the 1366 is the more 'power user' chip while the 1156 is the 'mainstream' chip.

For example, the 1366 supports triple channel DDR3 RAM while the 1156 only supports dual channel.

For your power-hungry tasks, I'd recommend the 1366. Also, when you upgrade later, you can get a higher-end 1366.

Comment: About the dual/tripple what is really the difference in real world performane?

Comment: Very little, for typical workloads. eg. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-core-i5,2410-6.html. All the i7s are massively fast as it is; going for the top of that range is very hard to justify. With modern hardware CAD/CAM isn't the workstation-killer it once was; I think I would struggle to spend $2k, personally.

Comment: :) I think I'll go for the 1156 then.. and I think I'll shrink my budget to 1500.. I spent sometime choosing stuff from an online catalog and that seems to give me a quite decent computer :)

Comment: Glad you came to a decision. Can't really go wrong either way, the i7's are fantastic. Good luck to you!

Comment: Triple channel memory access was needed for good performance on the 6 core 1366 chips. For the quads it was usually overkill. It did get momstly 6 DIMM sockets on the motherboard though, rather than only the regular 4 sockets.